# Proving $4!\binom{n+3}{4}$ is not the square of an integer

Tags: combinatorics

In an attempt to prove that the *product of four consecutive natural numbers cannot be the square of an integer*, I figured I'd go the combinatorics route (as I'm currently studying that field). I've managed to coerce as follows:
$$n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3) = 4!\begin{pmatrix}n+3 \\ 4\end{pmatrix}$$

(I see now that it's equally useful to use $24\binom{n}{4}$)

From here I'd like to show that the quantity on the right-hand side cannot be the square of an integer. I'm unsure how to go about this. Any help would be appreciated.

**Note:** I'm aware that a simpler proof can be found in other ways, but would like to gain a combinatorics-based intuition about why this quanitity cannot describe the square of an integer.

Comment: if you add one to the sum of four consecutive positive integers, you do get a square

Comment: Why do you say the two sides are equal?  The right hand is $\frac {(n+3)!}{24}$.  Did you just mean $4!$ instead of $(n-1)!$?

Comment: I'm looking into where the fallacy in the proof thus far is... please bear with me.

Comment: It has been rectified, thank you all. There was an issue in the use of a falling factorial.

Comment: I can't think of any reason or intuition reason combinatorics should forbid squares other than combinatorics have lots of close together factors and it'd be weird for them all to have even number of prime factors when they are close together (and thus relatively prime) and squares are far apart.  But this is basically just a restating that products of consecutive numbers tend not to be squares which is *far* more intuitive.  I can't see why you are doing this.

Comment: It's not generally easy to determine what the factors of binomial coefficients are. There's [Lucas's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem) which will just tell you that the first or second ternary digit of $n+3$ must be $0$, and the third binary digit of $n+3$ must be zero. I agree with @fleablood that trying to use combinatorics does not seem like a fruitful approach to this problem.

Answer (score 3):

$$n\left(n+1\right)\left(n+2\right)\left(n+3\right)=\left[n\left(n+3\right)\right]\left[\left(n+1\right)\left(n+2\right)\right]\\=\left(n^2+3n\right)\left(n^2+3n+2\right)=\left(n^2+3n+1\right)^2-1\\\because n^2+3n+1\ge1+3+1=5\\ \therefore\left(n^2+3n\right)^2<n\left(n+1\right)\left(n+2\right)\left(n+3\right)=\left(n^2+3n+1\right)^2-1<\left(n^2+3n+1\right)^2$$
There is no natural number $n$ that $n\left(n+1\right)\left(n+2\right)\left(n+3\right)$ is a perfect square.

Comment: This answer, while providing the common "textbook" proof directly opposes my question's request. While it has been agreed that combinatorics is not an ideal platform for solving this problem, I still wait for a solution rooted (likely) in an understanding of the binomial coefficients.